# Using string enums in NHibernate - GetValue never gets fired

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

In my NHibernate driven app I have classes where some properties of the class are not full blown entities. I.e., I have a customer class that has 
a customer type property. It seems a waste of resources to create a separate class for the customer type property.
What I'm trying to do is to map the customer type to an enum string in NHibernate 3.2 using mapping by code. Searching on StackOverflow, 
I found a possible solution with the following code:

```
   public class Customer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerMap : ClassMapping<Customer>
    {

        public CustomerMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Name, m => m.Length(100));
            Property(x => x.CustomerType, m =>
                     {
                         m.Column("CustomerTypeId");
                         m.Type(typeof (CustomerTypeMap), null);
                     });

        }
    }

    public enum CustomerType
    {
        Big_Customer,
        Small_Customer
    }

    public class CustomerTypeMap : EnumStringType<CustomerType>       
    {
        public override object GetValue(object code)
        {
            return code == null
                    ? string.Empty
                    : code.ToString().Replace('_', ' ');
        }

        public override object GetInstance(object code)
        {

            var str = (string)code;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return StringToObject(str);
            else return StringToObject(str.Replace(" ", "_"));
        }
    }
```

This solution works only partially. As you see from the code, I'm trying to make the enum string look nice by replacing the underscores in order to get "Big customer" instead of "Big_Customer". This doesn't work. Putting break lines into the code, I noticed that the overrriden GetInstance function gets called as it is supposed to, but the GetValue function never gets fired. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the underscores in the first place? The ".Netty" way of naming enum member would be BigCustomer and SmallCustomer.

Comment: @Oskar - I think it's obvious from the code. I would like a nice output, so BigCustomer is out of the question. The easiest way seems to be to have and underscore have replaced by a space.

Answer (score 0):

I agree you shouldn't create a new entity for something like CustomerType. NHibernate doesn't expect you to either. Fluent NHibernate will map enums as strings by default (I assume you're using the latest version), but apparently you want to have more fine-grained control.

It's been a while since I used Fluent NH, but maybe try this (unless the API has been changed):

```
Map(x => x.CustomerType).Column("CustomerTypeId").CustomType<CustomerTypeMap>();
```

Once again, not sure if this (still) works as the API changed/changes a lot.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate's 3.2 mapping by code and the solution I presented does work partially. The thing that doesn't work is the replacing of underscores because the overriden GetValue() never gets called.